# Using fastlane with an app that uses a notification extension

Tags: ios, fastlane

I am using fastlane to build and send my app to testflight. This worked until I added a Notification Extension. Now it always gives me the error:

> Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=9
>   ""OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex" requires a provisioning
>   profile with the App Groups feature."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription="OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex" requires a provisioning profile with the App Groups feature.,
>   NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Add a profile to the
>   "provisioningProfiles" dictionary in your Export Options property
>   list.}

Everything is supposed to be handled automatically on Xcode, and my fastfile looks like this:

```
default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do
  before_all do
    increment_build_number
  end

  desc "Push a new beta build to TestFlight"
  lane :beta do
    get_certificates           # invokes cert
    get_provisioning_profile   # invokes sigh
    build_app(workspace: "MyApp.xcworkspace", scheme: "MyApp (Production)")
    pilot(skip_waiting_for_build_processing: true)
  end
end
```

My bundle identifier for my app is like com.myapp.ios and my bundle identifier for my notification service is like com.myapp.ios.notificationservice.

I've tried creating multiple provisioning profiles for the different bundle identifiers manually, but fastlane only selects one. How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you find a solution to this ?

Comment: @cdn34 Yep, I just added my answer below. Let me know if that helps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed this by changing my manually specifying the provisioning profiles in my fastfile like this:

```
default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do
  before_all do
    increment_build_number
  end

  desc "Push a new beta build to TestFlight"
  lane :beta do
    get_certificates           # invokes cert
    get_provisioning_profile   # invokes sigh
    build_app(workspace: "MyApp.xcworkspace", 
    scheme: "MyApp (Production)", 
    export_method: "app-store",
        export_options: {
            provisioningProfiles: { 
                "com.myapp.ios" => "com.myapp.ios AppStore 1530397498",
                "com.myapp.ios.OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension" => "MyApp Notification Extension Provisioning Profile"
            }
        })
    pilot(skip_waiting_for_build_processing: true)
  end
end
```

If you want to use match, you can replace `export_options` with  this:

```
match(
    app_identifier:["com.myapp.ios","com.myapp.ios.OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension"],
    type: "appstore"
)
```

Comment: Hi do u have answer that use “match”?

Comment: @LêKhánhVinh Hi, yes actually I use match now, so I've added in my match code above! Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks. but in CI server (bitrise) I can not use match (need login with 2FA Authentication)

Comment: @LêKhánhVinh I'm using match with CircleCI for CI so it defo works. It's recommended to create a new App Store Connect account just for the build server and turn off 2FA. That's what I do!